# 'Object of class Illuminate\Mail\Mailer could not be converted to string'

Tags: php, email, laravel, laravel-5.1

I am trying to send an e-mail confirmation for registration. I have created `app>Mailers>AppMailer`.

```
class AppMailer {

  protected $mailer;

  protected $from = 'admin@example.com';

  protected $to;

  protected $view;

  protected $data = [];


  public function __construct(Mailer $mailer)
  {
    $this->$mailer = $mailer;   // Line 23
  }
```

However, I am getting an error:

> ErrorException in AppMailer.php line 23:
>
> Object of class Illuminate\Mail\Mailer could not be converted to string

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Set `$this->mailer`, not `$this->$mailer`.

---

So instead of this:

```php
$this->$mailer = $mailer;
    // ^
```

Use this:

```php
$this->mailer = $mailer;
```